# Filter std::vector of std::string's

Tags: c++, boost, c++98

How can I produce an output vector which filters an input vector based on whether it starts with a certain sub-string or not. I'm using c++98 and boost.

This is as far as I got:

```
std::string stringToFilterBy("2");
std::vector<std::string> input = boost::assign::list_of("1")("2")("22")("33")("222");
std::vector<int> output;
boost::copy( input | boost::adaptors::filtered(boost::starts_with), std::back_inserter(output) );
```

Comment: You could use `regex` as the filter, which is part of boost & c++11

Comment: @Haocheng But isn't a starts_with predicate more efficient than a regex?

Comment: Can't test right now, but I think you want `boost::bind(boost::starts_with<std::string,std::string>(), _1, stringToFilterBy)` as your predicate. So when the filter adaptor calls the predicate with the element `x`, it calls `boost::starts_with(x, stringToFilterBy)`.

Comment: @Baz Yes...I didn't catch your point just now

Comment: @Steve Jessop boost::copy( input | boost::bind(boost::starts_with<std::string,std::string>(), _1, stringToFilterBy), std::back_inserter(output) ); This doesn't compile. Complier complains that starts_with doesn't take zero arguments.

Comment: @Baz: oh, `starts_with` is a function, I thought it was a functor class. Remove the `()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [std::remove_copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove_copy) instead:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

struct filter : public std::unary_function<std::string, bool> {
    filter(const std::string &by) : by_(by) {}
    bool operator()(const std::string &s) const {
        return s.find(by_) == 0;
    }

    std::string by_;
};

std::vector<std::string> in, out;
std::remove_copy_if(in.begin(), in.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
                    std::not1(filter("2")));
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work: std::remove_copy_if ( input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output), boost::bind(&boost::starts_with<std::string,std::string>, _1, stringToFilterBy) );

Comment: @Baz I seldom use boost, so I really can't say.

Comment: @Baz I finally installed boost and tested your filter `starts_with`. `remove_copy_if` removes all elements, where `filter` returns `true`. So, the fix to this seems to be negating the condition. I did the same mistake with my `struct filter` and fixed it accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

One way is:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string stringToFilterBy("2");
    std::vector<std::string> input =
        boost::assign::list_of("1")("2")("22")("33")("222");
    std::vector<int> output;
    boost::copy(
        input
      | boost::adaptors::filtered(
            boost::bind(
                boost::starts_with<std::string,std::string>, _1, stringToFilterBy))
      | boost::adaptors::transformed(boost::lexical_cast<int, std::string>),
        std::back_inserter(output));
}
```

Or without `boost::bind` (this way avoids naming types and avoids the need for function pointers, but requires the addition of some single-use structs):

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/predicate.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptor/transformed.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template<typename Range1T>
struct StartsWith_T {
    StartsWith_T(Range1T const& test) : test(&test) {}
    template<typename Range2T>
    bool operator()(Range2T const& input) const {
        return boost::starts_with(input, *test);
    }
    Range1T const* test;
};

template<typename Range1T>
StartsWith_T<Range1T> StartsWith(Range1T const& test) {
    return StartsWith_T<Range1T>(test);
}

template<typename T>
struct LexicalCaster {
    typedef T result_type;
    template<typename Input>
    T operator()(Input const& input) const {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(input);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::string stringToFilterBy("2");
    std::vector<std::string> input =
        boost::assign::list_of("1")("2")("22")("33")("222");
    std::vector<int> output;

    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    boost::copy(
        input
      | filtered(StartsWith(stringToFilterBy))
      | transformed(LexicalCaster<int>()),
        std::back_inserter(output));
}
```

Comment: The second listing doesn't compile for me - lots of template errors - I'm trying to work out what it is...

Comment: @Caribou: my fault... let me get a fixed version up

Comment: @Caribou: They should both now work. (I was missing `result_type`, serves me right for testing it on a C++11 compiler).

Comment: I was having fun there - I've never used this aspect of boost :P - debugging stuff like this makes you learn more :)

Comment: @Caribou: Oh, if that's it I can supply you with a never ending supply of broken code :P

Comment: That's ok I have much of my own, interesting that the missing typedef caused so much havoc - lots of implicit dependencies there

Comment: +1, replaces my comment above with actual working code. And also I didn't notice the destination vector is `int`, not `string`. Is the `bind` needed around `lexical_cast`?

Comment: There's something wrong when a task which for 99% of programmers would be a five line for loop causes some C++ programmers to produce reams of complex templated code. I know there's an intellectual challenge to writing such code, but there is no way you can look at the final result and say that it's good.

Comment: @SteveJessop: the `bind` isn't needed, fixed.

Comment: @john: the problem is that there's no way in C++ to write code concisely in a functional style. People want to write in that style because it has its benefits, but as you say in C++ the result is often a pageful of tricky code that could be a simple loop. Lambdas in C++11 can improve things a bit.

Comment: But then again, C++11 also improves the for loop: `for (auto &s : input) { if (boost::starts_with(s, stringToFilterBy)) output.push_back(boost::lexical_cast<int>(s)); }`. In practice the algorithm/iterator/predicate style is helpful for abstracting classes of tasks like this, it's rarely helpful for solving just one at a time.

Comment: @john late response but yes I know what you mean. I generally don't use boost unless I have to. This kind of problem for me helps me to understand more about the subtleties of C++ TBH - I let a large amount slip past me in my time because I have (or at least thought) i had no need for it.